# Comparar valores de 2 arrays diferentes com JS

Tags: javascript

estou tentando comparar valores de 2 arrays diferentes, sendo que um já tem numeros salvos nele e o outro é preenchido pelo usuario, quando tento fazer o IF para comparar todos os valores de um array com o outro, ele está retornando "true" porque está validando somente o primeiro índice de um array com o outro.

Quando fiz a comparação dessa forma: //(sorteados[0,1,2,3,4,5] == nao_Sorteados[0,1,2,3,4,5]) , deu certo, mas quero fazer ele comparando indice a indice pelo loop.

```
       for (i = 0; i < nao_Sorteados.length; i++) {                 
        for (x = 0; x < sorteados.length; x++) {                      
            if (sorteados[x] == nao_Sorteados[i]) {
             alert("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
             return;
               }
            }
        } alert("Infelizmente você errou");
     }
```

Comment: Imagina duas arrays: `[0, 2, 1]` e `[0, 1, 2]`. O resultado da comparação deveria ser positivo ou negativo? Ou seja: procuras que sejam idênticas inclusive na posição dos elementos? (e outra pergunta: só tens 1 nível de profundidade ou cada elemento da array pode ter sub-arrays?)

Answer (score 6):

Existem várias formas de comparar os dados de um array.

Considerando que você tem um array simples, sendo apenas um vetor sem objetos complexos, podemos por exemplo criar uma função e fazer um `for`, comparando os dados com base no índice do array:

```js
function comparaArrays(sorteados, nao_Sorteados) {
  if (sorteados.length != nao_Sorteados.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < nao_Sorteados.length; i++) {                 
      if (sorteados[i] !== nao_Sorteados[i]) {
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array1, array2)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}

const array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array3, array4)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}
```

Perceba que caso os arrays não tenha o mesmo tamanho, já considero que eles não são iguais.

---

Seguindo a mesma lógica anterior, podemos utilizar o método `every` do array, encurtando bastante nosso código:

```js
function comparaArrays(sorteados, nao_Sorteados) {
  if (sorteados.length != nao_Sorteados.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return nao_Sorteados.every( (value, index) => value === sorteados[index] );
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array1, array2)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}

const array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array3, array4)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}
```

---

Também podemos optar por uma opção simples, convertendo o array para string e comparando os resultados:

```js
function comparaArrays(sorteados, nao_Sorteados) {
  return nao_Sorteados.toString() === sorteados.toString();
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array1, array2)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}

const array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];

if (comparaArrays(array3, array4)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}
```

---

***Obs:** Se você deseja comparar os dados independente da ordenação, você poderia chamar o método `sort` antes de efetuar a comparação dos dados:*

```js
function comparaArrays(sorteados, nao_Sorteados) {
  if (sorteados.length != nao_Sorteados.length) {
    return false;
  }

  sorteados.sort();
  return nao_Sorteados.sort().every( (value, index) => value === sorteados[index] );
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

if (comparaArrays(array1, array2)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}
```

É válido citar que o método `sort` vai alterar o array original, caso você não queira que isso venha acontecer, pode utilizar do método `slice` antes do `sort`, criando assim uma cópia do array, dessa forma o array enviado para a função não sofrerá qualquer alteração:

```js
function comparaArrays(sorteados, nao_Sorteados) {
  if (sorteados.length != nao_Sorteados.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  const paraComparar = sorteados.slice().sort();

  return nao_Sorteados.slice().sort().every( (value, index) => value === paraComparar[index] );
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

console.log("Array antes: ", array2);

if (comparaArrays(array1, array2)) {
  console.log("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
} else {
  console.log("Infelizmente você errou");
}

console.log("Array depois: ", array2);
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma maneira bem simples de fazer isso, caso você não esteja lidando com objetos, basta fazer:

```
if(vetor1.toString() === vetor2.toString()){
  console.log('São iguais');
}else{
  console.log('Não são iguais');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

obrigado...deu certo, estou aprendendo a programar ainda então sou meio ignorante no assunto ainda, talvez tenha faltado mais detalhes da minha parte, consegui fazer o código fazer a validação utilizando o  if (sorteados.toString() === nao_Sorteados.toString()), dessa forma, o meu código completo ficou assim:

```
<script>


         const sorteados = [10,55,48,30,22,60]
         const nao_Sorteados = []

         function validar(){       

          let max = 6;
            if(nao_Sorteados.length < max){
            alert("Por favor, insira todos os numeros");
            return;
                }

            for (i = 0; i < nao_Sorteados.length; i++) {
             for (x = 0; x < sorteados.length; x++) { //if(sorteio.indexOf(jogo[i]) > -1)                 
               if (sorteados.toString() === nao_Sorteados.toString()) {  //(sorteados[0,1,2,3,4,5] == nao_Sorteados[0,1,2,3,4,5])
                alert("Parabéns, você acertou tudo");
                return;
           }
        }

     }  alert("Infelizmente você errou");

   }

        function adicionar(){
         let max = 6;
         escolhido = document.getElementById('array2').value
                     document.getElementById('array2').value = ""

         if(escolhido == ""){
          alert("Digite um valor valido");
          return;
        }         

         for(let i=0;i<nao_Sorteados.length;i++){
          if(nao_Sorteados[i] == escolhido){
          alert("Esse numero ja foi escolhido");
             console.log(nao_Sorteados);
                        return;
                    }

                } nao_Sorteados.push(escolhido);
                  console.log(nao_Sorteados);


            //Não necessario o return pois é a ultima condição do codigo
               if (nao_Sorteados.length > max) {
               alert("Você ja escolheu todos os numeros");
               nao_Sorteados.pop(escolhido);
               console.log(nao_Sorteados);                 

            } 
        }

</script>
```